# In Perl, how can I store arrays as values in a hash?

Tags: regex, perl, hashtable

I don't know if you're allowed to ask questions about a school assignment. I just want to understand what I am supposed to do, not do this for me. Maybe I am missing something so simple it is right in front of me but anyways it was based off of an older assignment, but I had missed this class and I am running into a wall now, and well the problem is that I'm trying to push an array into a hash table. using something like this;

```
push @{$hash_table{$hash_key}}, $port
```

and to count the ports while storing them and then to print the contents of the hash

```
while ( ($key , $value) = each ( %hash ) ) {
    print “$key scanned @{$value}” 
}
```

and if I wanted to sort the results I would use

```
< foreach $key ( keys ( %hash ) ) {
}
```

The current code I have is this, searching for the string of /iNext-DROP/
using a log file provided. I cant for the life of me find the correct place to add the code above

```
use warnings;
my $LogRecord; 
my $LogRecordCount;
open LOGFILE, "sample.log.txt" or die "couldn't open sample.log.txt";
while ($LogRecord = <LOGFILE>) {
if  ($LogRecord =~ /INext-DROP/)    { 
    $LogRecordCount ++;
    $LogRecord =~ /(SRC=[0-9\.]* ).*(SPT=[0-9\.]* )/;
    $source=$1;
    $sport=$2;
print "$source$sport"; 
print substr( $LogRecord , 0 , $ARGV[1] ) , "\n"  if $ARGV[1];
 }
}
print "The file contained $LogRecordCount records" if $ARGV[1];
close LOGFILE;
```

Here's a picture of the old code with comments ;
[Old Code -- not much has changed since I keep going back after it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD9fc.png)

Comment: You're absolutely allowed to ask about assignments - the same rules apply as for 'real' questions though. e.g. We won't do your work (homework or otherwise) for you. We will help you understand your problem and fix the code you're working on.

Comment: A snippet of log pasted (so we don't have to reconstruct from screenshot) would help for testing.

Comment: comments don't format well [edit] your post with it please.

Comment: We don't need all of it, just a few lines is enough for testing what your code actually does with that input.

Comment: Do not delete the content of your question.

Comment: I'll put in a request to delete the account.

Comment: You do not get to ask a question, get a perfect answer, and just wipe out everything. That is not how Stackoverflow works. FYI @Sobrique.

Comment: Yeah would you rather someone else that has the same assignment next semester able to google this answer? Probably not. But what use does this have to anyone other than this specific assignment?

Comment: The purpose to Stack Overflow is providing a source of reference. Answering your question is a side effect that's beneficial. But it's important to preserve both question and answer so it _can_ serve as that reference. And yes, it might allow people to google this assignment next semester. But maybe they're having the same problem.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free one-on-one tutoring service. The act of asking a question and having it answered creates a bit of knowledge that did not exist before. The purpose of Stackoverflow is to drive visitors to the site by sharing that knowledge. If the knowledge was only meant to be transferred to you, we would be working as private tutors for individual questioners. For that service, you will have to pay.

Answer (score 3):

The thing you're seemingly having problems with, is that you're not sure where the port is being captured and the hash update.

What's happening is your `while` loop is iterating the file one line at a time, and capturing values - that `$LogRecord =~` line is capturing a pattern - into `$1` and `$2`.

And then that `$2` is the thing you can add to your hash, with `push`.

However, there's a few things I have changed style wise like using lexical file handles because it's better style.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

#because it makes debugging easier. 
use Data::Dumper;

my $LogRecordCount;

#declare some hashes; 
my %ports_from; 
my %ips_that_used; 

open my $logfile, "sample.log.txt" or die "couldn't open sample.log.txt";
while (my $line = <$logfile>) {
    #matches 'current line' - skips stuff that doesn't match. 
    next unless $line =~ /INext-DROP/; 
    #increment count. 
    $LogRecordCount++;

    my ( $source, $src_port ) = $line =~ m/SRC=([0-9\.]+).*SPT=([0-9]+)/;  
    print "$source$sport"; 

    #not sure what this is doing, so I have left it in. 
    print substr( $line , 0 , $ARGV[1] ) , "\n"  if $ARGV[1];

    push @{$ports_from{$source}}, $src_port; 
    push @{$ips_that_used{$src_port}}, $source; 
 }
print "The file contained $LogRecordCount records" if $ARGV[1];
close $logfile;

print Dumper \%ports_from;
print Dumper \%ips_that_used;
```

That's built up your hashes.

But when it comes to outputing:

```
foreach my $ip ( keys %ports_from ) { 
  print "$ip: ", join ( " ", @{$ports_from{$ip}}) ,"\n"
}
```

If you wanted to sort them, you would have to do this using `sort`.

Now `sort` is a pretty clever function, but by default is sorts alphanumerically. That's ... actually not all that useful when it comes to IP addresses or port numbers, because you probably want to sort those more numerically. The easy answer is `Sort::Naturally` and use `nsort`.

However - `sort` takes a function (it defaults to `cmp`) that returns -1, 0, 1 depending on relative position.

So sorting 'by IP' might look like this:

```
sub by_ip { 
   my @a = split /\./, $a;
   my @b = split /\./, $b; 
   foreach my $octet ( @a ) { 
      my $comparison = $octet <=> shift ( @b ); 
      return $comparison if $comparison; 
   }
   return 0;
}
```

And then you could:

```
foreach my $ip ( sort by_ip keys %ports_from ) { 
   print "$ip: ", join ( " ", sort { $a <=> $b } @{$ports_from{$ip}}),"\n";
}
```

Giving you:

```
24.64.208.134 : 24128  24128  24128 
71.228.199.109 : 37091 
72.197.8.56 : 9258 
75.117.31.43 : 3122 
99.248.20.48 : 48725 
207.68.178.56 : 80
```

Given an IP-to-port mapping where duplicates exist though, it might be better still to merely count port-frequency using a hash-of-hashes instead of a hash-of-arrays.

```
$count_ports_from{$source}{$src_port}++;
```

And then:

```
foreach my $ip ( sort by_ip keys %count_ports_from ) {
   print "$ip: ";
   foreach my $port_num ( sort { $count_ports_from{$a} <=> $count_ports_from{$b} } 
       keys %{ $count_ports_from{$ip} } )
   {
      print "\t $port_num : $count_ports_from{$ip}{$port_num}\n";
   }
}
```

Giving you something like:

```
24.64.208.134 :      24128  : 3
71.228.199.109 :     37091  : 1
72.197.8.56 :    9258  : 1
75.117.31.43 :   3122  : 1
99.248.20.48 :   48725  : 1
207.68.178.56 :      80  : 1
```

Comment: Wow thank you for this explanation it's helping, I think I should be okay from here now.

Comment: Perhaps. A default 'sort' isn't as useful as it sounds with IPs and numbers - you often need something more specific.